# Should all classes be testable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write unit tests for a new project I have created and I've run into an issue where I can't work out how a class that I am intending to write is actually testable. Below I've simplified the class that I am trying to write to give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

So I have an XML parser that will simply access an XML file from a given URL, extract the data that I need and return it as an object. So my code will look something like this (Validation and population not completed yet but you get the idea):

```
public UserDetails ParseUserDetails(string request, string username, string password)
{
    var response = new XmlDocument();
    response.Load(string.Format(request + "?user={0}&password={1}", username, password));

    // Validation checks

    return new UserDetails { // Populate object with XML nodes };
}
```

Currently my class isn't testable. I can't mock the load to throw a WebException to see how my class handles errors and until I pass through a valid URL it will always throw an exception when I run tests against this class. I also cannot test the data coming back from the class since I can't mock the XML document since it's loaded from another URL.

I could split this out into a mockable object that retrieves the XML from the URL and name it something like IXmlDocumentLoader but later I run into the same problem where I have a class like this:

```
public class XmlDocumentLoader : IXmlDocumentLoader
{
    public XmlDocument LoadXmlDocument(string request, string username, string password)
    {
        var response = new XmlDocument();
        response.Load(string.Format(request + "?user={0}&password={1}", username, password));

        return response;
    }
}
```

This would make the ParseUserDetails method more testable but now the class XmlDocumentLoader is not testable. So have I just moved the problem elsewhere? My question is really do all classes have to be testable or am I misunderstanding unit testing?

Comment: In my _opinion_ unit testing should only cover business logic. Any standard library functionality, which is expected to _just work_ and any logic, which relies on external resources, like web servers, database, and so on, should not be unit tested. Testing of those pieces is _integration testing_ in my book.

Comment: If something is going to have validation checks that must mean it can pass or fail validation. Can you not set up a test which will pass in a UserDetails object that should fail and one which should pass and test that, on the subject of validation have you looked at Fluent Validation?

Comment: This is because you have two concerns tied together - fetching the XML data and parsing it into an object. Separate out the concept of fetching the data into an `XmlRepository` or something, and pass an instance of `IXmlRepository` into the parser.

Comment: I suggest you may have more success if you can define exactly what it is you want to test... rather than "the class" is it the download? Is it that credentials are passed correctly? Is it that the url is correct? Answering these questions will push you towards understanding how to test your code. However IMHO 500 raises a good point, any abstraction is likely to have exactly the same signature as what you've already got and is therefore redundant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This for sure is an "opinion" question, and as so, probably will be closed.

But I'll give you a suggestion.

Split everything. Use the principle of "an object should do only one thing". Donwload a file is one thing, validate it is another one. If you separete both, you can test both.

You can test your download system on a generic file (do not have to be a production site), and test if the system works. And you can provide a "fake file" to test the validation, that also do not have to be a production file.

Both tests will give you an idea of how much your code is working as expected.

Comment: I pretty much did this and split the XML code out into another area. I didn't know whether it was a bit over engineered but it's made everything testable so it's probably worth it

Answer (score 2):

The [XmlDocument.Load(string filename) documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) defines the `filename` parameter thusly:

> *filename*: URL for the file containing the XML document to load. The URL can be **either a local file** or an HTTP URL (a Web address).

(emphasis mine)

So your code is entirely testable if your `ParseUserDetails` tests pass something like `file://C:/path/to/my/test/file`  as the `request` parameter. They might look something like this:

```
    public void SomeRandomTest()
    {
        string testFileLocalPath = @"C:\path\to\my\test\file";
        // Code to create an XML file with expected data goes here ...

        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder();
        ub.Scheme = "file";
        ub.Host = "";
        ub.Path = testFileLocalPath;
        string request = ub.ToString();

        var target = new SomethingThatReadsXml();
        var details = target.ParseUserDetails(request, "dummy", "whocares");

        // Compare returned user details to expected values here ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't that easy, I disagree with the opinion that this code should be intended to work and does not need testing. Personally I would make Integration tests that test the actual real life situation that you can run during build or so.

To make the LOGIC testable i would split this thing up (like you've mentioned) and make your Parser work with a Stream (or sth. equivalent). The good thing about IO-Code that is based on Streams is, that you can fake data with MemoryStreams, so you could test your Parser by XML code that is written in your test. To test the other thing that retrieves the XML from web and returns it as a Stream is a bit more complicated to simulate, but the logic should be much easier you simply have to test the inputs and some Integration tests with an invalid URL/credentials/... the actual retrieving is really the .Net implementation (that you don't have to test).

At the end, you will reach an external boundary that you can not fake, but the xml parser should not be that end ;)

Here you can see an example:
[VS Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/16/unit-testing-in-c-sharp.aspx)